# pyqtdeploy GUI does not start

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, pyqtdeploy

I have installed python3.4, Qt5.5 and PyQt5 on Ubuntu 14.04.
Pyqtdeploy was installed with

`pip3 install pyqtdeploy`

Now if I try to make a new project file and start the gui with:

`pyqtdeploy newproject.pdy`

I get a couple of these error messages (all the same):

`(python3:26052): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed`

And I see a window frame of the pyqtdeploy application but it is empty (transparent) and the compiz process uses a lot of cpu resources (kind of freezing the os)

The Ubuntu 14.04 is installed in virtualbox on a windows 7 host.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working now, the error seemed to be that pyqtdeploy which is a python/PyQt5 application used the default styletheme (think its gtk+) which somehow causes problems.
I set the fusion style in the file main_gui.py (in source code of pyqtdeploy):

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))`